# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (5024, 2) instead

Tags: python

Here is my Python code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('sme_loan.csv', sep=',',dtype=str)
#print(df)
df2 = df.drop(columns=['problem'])

xx = df2.to_numpy()

yy = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['problem'])

yyy = np.ravel(yy)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(xx)

xxx = enc.transform(xx).toarray()

clf = LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear").fit(xxx, yy)

result = roc_auc_score(yyy, clf.predict_proba(xxx), multi_class='ovr')

print("df:")
print(df)
print("xx:")
print(xx)
print("xxx:")
print(xxx)
print("yy:")
print(yy)
print("yyy:")
print(yyy)
```

Here is the error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\jupyter\r\r.py", line 30, in <module>
...
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (5024, 2) instead.
```

I am trying to calculate AUC score. I could not convert shape into 1d array. I tried flatten() and ravel(yy), but did not help. Help prease!

Comment: Please add the complete traceback.
You should also check `clf = LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear").fit(xxx, yyy)`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that it is not `yyy` that is giving this error, but `clf.predict_proba(xxx)`.

[predict_proba()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba) returns an array of size `(n_samples, n_classes)`. Assuming you have 2 classes, that is why you have an array of shape (5024, 2).

If you are comparing a 1d-array of predicted classes against a 1d-array of actual classes of the same size, replace `predict_proba()` with [predict()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict) instead to get the predicted classes and not the predicted probabilities.